# Echo Option Value Based On Wordpress User Role

Tags: php, wordpress

If someone can figure this out, man you would make my week!

Basically what I'm trying to do is echo a different value in a option based on a the users role on Wordpress.

If user is administrator echo = user@email.com
If user is subscriber echo = admin@email.com

Here is the code I am working with:

```
    if ( ! empty( $note_emails ) || $include_custom ) { ?>
        <div class="gv-note-email-container">
            <label for="gv-note-email-to-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>" class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo $strings['also-email'];  ?></label>
            <select class="gv-note-email-to" name="gv-note-to" id="gv-note-email-to-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>">
                <?php foreach ( $note_emails as  $email ) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="admin@email.com">admin@email.com</option>
                <?php }
                if( $include_custom ) { ?>
                <option value="custom"><?php echo self::strings('other-email'); ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <fieldset class="gv-note-to-container">
                <?php if( $include_custom ) { ?>
                <div class='gv-note-to-custom-container'>
                    <label for="gv-note-email-to-custom-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>"><?php echo $strings['email-label']; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="gv-note-to-custom" placeholder="<?php echo $strings['email-placeholder']; ?>" id="gv-note-to-custom-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>" value="" />
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
                <div class='gv-note-subject-container'>
                    <label for="gv-note-subject-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>"><?php echo $strings['subject-label']; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="gv-note-subject" placeholder="<?php echo $strings['subject']; ?>" id="gv-note-subject-<?php echo $entry_slug_esc; ?>" value="" />
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    <?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //This user is administrator
}
```